# Why does my iPhone keep crashing except on low power mode?

Tags: iphone, battery, crash

I have a one year old iPhone 5s.  After about six months of use it started crashing and restarting.  This often happens when launching an app, when I imagine power consumption may be at its highest.  Through trial and error I noticed that enabling low power mode prevents crashes entirely.  Without low power mode I get about one crash per few hours.  I have tried wiping the OS and reinstalling to no avail.

What's happening and what can I do to fix the problem?

In case it's relevant I will describe what I see during the crash and reboot.  The normal Apple white startup logo appears on a black screen and occasionally when it crashes there are thin vertical red and blue lines.

Comment: The 5s was discontinued almost 2 years ago.  Did you buy it used or refurb from Apple?  Do you still have AppleCare on it?  Have you tried to wipe it completely and reinstall the OS (not from a backup)?

Comment: Could it be related to this? *Accused of Slowing Old iPhones, Apple Offers Battery Discounts* (NY Times) https://is.gd/SUUlch

Comment: @fsb Yes, I have tried reinstalling (I added this information to my question).  I got the phone from a carrier.  I understood it to be new and I don't have any reason to think otherwise.